# Easy way to replace an YAML array of IDs with strings from a joined table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, array

I have a database full of camp data. Each camp has many campers and has many camp_weeks.

In the table of campers, there is a YAML encoded array of IDs for the camper's camp weeks. The project requires a query for display. Here's a sample row from the campers table:

```
19770,'Daniela',41,'---
- 406
- 407
')
```

My current query ([based on the excellent tip from this blog](http://glen-noronha.blogspot.com/2012/07/searching-through-yaml-encoded-arrays.html)):

```
SELECT 
  campers.name,
  camps.id,
  camps.title,
  regexp_split_to_array(trim(regexp_replace(campers.camp_weeks, E'[\\n\\r''-]+', ' ', 'g' )), E'\\D+') AS week_array
FROM 
  campers
LEFT JOIN camps ON campers.camp_id = camps.id
GROUP BY camps.id, campers.id
```

returns the campers, with a string/array of camp ids like this:

```
====================================
|  Daniela | 41 | sports | 406,407 |
====================================
```

I would like the query to return

```
============================================
|  Daniela | 41 | sports | cricket, tennis |
============================================
```

What would be an easy way to do this?

Performance is not a big issue for this query and the simpler the query is the better it will be.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4f28c/8).

Comment: Why are you storing your data like this? Fix the root problem: your data model!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Colin 't Hart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66213/easy-way-to-replace-an-yaml-array-of-ids-with-strings-from-a-joined-table#comment121236_66213)'s comment is 100% correct - your data model fails on the first letter of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).  YAML is fine for serialization of objects for application consumption, but since your data layer is a RDBMS, you should stick to the RDBMS paradigms.  Assuming you don't have the permission to migrate to a better structure and probably force a re-code of the application, the good news is that you're halfway there with your original query already:  Instead of going straight to array ( `regexp_split_to_array` ), split to table ( `regexp_split_to_table` ) instead, then perform a join on `camp_weeks` for the names.  You could then group that for the stuffed string listing ( using `string_agg` if it's available on your version of postgres, like shown below ), or pass the results as-is, letting the application worry about the presentation layer.

```
SELECT  a.name,
        a.id,
        a.title,
        string_agg( cw.week_name, ', ' )
             AS week_names
FROM (  SELECT  cs.id
                    AS camper_id,
                cs.name,
                c.id,
                c.title,
                regexp_split_to_table( trim( 
                    regexp_replace( 
                        cs.camp_weeks, 
                        E'[\\n\\r''-]+',
                        ' ', 'g' ) 
                    ), E'\\D+' ) 
                    AS camp_week_id
        FROM    public.campers cs
        LEFT JOIN public.camps c
            ON  cs.camp_id = c.id ) a
LEFT JOIN public.camp_weeks cw
    ON  CAST( a.camp_week_id AS INTEGER ) = cw.id
GROUP BY a.name, a.id, a.camper_id, a.title
ORDER BY a.id, a.camper_id;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works like magic. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4f28c/29  Would love to fix the data model...